# is it possible to iteration from .begin() to .rbegin()

Tags: c++

I need to iterate from the beginning of a container to one element before the end. I can put an `if` condition inside the loop to bypass the last element but I was wondering if it would be possible to write the for loop like this:

```
for (it = C.begin(); it != C.rbegin(); it++){...}
```

if not, is there any suggestions?

Is it container dependent? (for now, I am using `std::vector` but it may change)

Comment: You can use `std::prev(C.end())`.

Comment: You just have to [try the code](http://ideone.com/26XVA0) to see: `prog.cpp:8:34: error: no match for ‘operator!=’ (operand types are ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >’ and ‘std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator {aka std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > >}’)`.  You can use the `.base()` member function on a `reverse_iterator` to get an iterator that can be compared to `end`, or use `std::prev` as 0x499602D2 suggests....

Comment: @TonyD :) I almost knew it was wrong, that is way I mentioned `like this:` and that is why I requested for suggestions, and that is why I put it on stackoverflow. Nice hint though.

Comment: @0x499602D2 need C++03 solution :(

Comment: `for (it = C.begin(), it_end(C.end()) , --it_end; it != it_end; it++){...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the comment by [Tony D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/410767/tony-d), you can use [`std::prev(C.end())`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) to get the iterator that precedes the end iterator:

```
for (it = C.begin(); it != std::prev(C.end()); it++);
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was looking for C++03.

Comment: good, thanks. just to make sure: 1- is `C.begin() + C.size() - 1` good for any type of container or just `std::vector` ?   2- will `it != C.end() -1` also work?(for any type of container)

Comment: @rahman `+` and `-` will only work for containers with random access iterators. So that would be `std::vector` and `std::array`.